# Golang object destructor for C/C++ bindings

Tags: go, cgo

We are building cryptorgraphic libraries with C/C++, and now adding also Golang support for it.
CGO binding works fine except one thing **We need to call some function to free C pointers from memory manually**.
Currently we are doing like this, by making some Go interface wrapper for cleaning up memory.

```
func SomeFunc() {
  cObj := NewObjectFromCPP()
  defer cObj.Free()
}
```

We also tried to use `runtime.SetFinilizer` to clean memory when Golang GC trying to clean wrapped object. BUT it turns out that `runtime.SetFinilizer` callback is not running every time, or not running at all, because in documentation it says *it will run eventually*.

Our current solution is hacky from my point of view, and wanted to get some input from people who already done something like this.

What is the right way of cleaning C/C++ memory from Go besides directly calling manual methods?

Comment: [This discussion may be helpful.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/DMiUkpS1uyQ) In summary, finalizers are not reliable in all circumstances, so unless you are aware of their limitations, use manual management instead, eg, with reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

The convention in Go for disposing of things going out of scope is to use defer(), as you are doing.

There is also another convention of using Close() as your disposal method, and in fact many parts of the library assume this convention (such as [Closer](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Closer)).

```
func doThings() {
    if thing, err := openThingHoldingResources(); err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error
    }
    defer thing.Close()

    // TODO: Do stuff with thing
}
```

One of the primary design goals of Go is to keep magic to a minimum, and functions that invoke automatically on object lifecycle events (constructors & destructors) is one of those magics they eschew.